# I used following code for downloading xml file from ftp in android it is giving exception?

Tags: android

I'm new to android, I used code from this site http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39810/1954 it is throwing exception while establishing connection with ftp.

Comment: Please indent your code. It's barely legible.

Comment: Do you really plan on programming in Java without even learning its syntax, just by asking questions on StackOverflow? Read the Java tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: +1 from me, I think newbie and basic questions are welcomed on SO. See meta.

Comment: @Gens: While newbie and basic questions are allowed here, this questions shows a remarkable lack of effort on Rajkumar's part.  The Java tutorial's are readily available.  We're not here to translate from .NET to Java for those who are too lazy to learn the language.

Comment: @Rajkumar Reddy: That is all I can help you, I can't argue with moderator. Moderator is the king here. When King says you are lazy then you are lazy.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ClsTest {
    private int intid;

    public int getIntid () {
        return intid;
    }

    public void setIntid (int intid) {
        this.intid = intid;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<ClsTest> objtest = new ArrayList<ClsTest>();
        objtest.add(new ClsTest());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below defines a ClsTest class with a single int field. To try this, copy the code into a file called ClsTest.java.

The [Object.equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Object.hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods are overridden so that ClsTest instances can participate in Collections in the way you probably want. That is, I expect you want two instances of ClsTest to be considered equal if they have the same intid.

Try commenting out the equals method to see what happens with [List.contains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) if you don't have it.

We don't exercise hashCode in this example, but it would be needed if you were including your objects in a Map. You should always implement equals and hashCode to complement each other.

Finally, in the main method, a ClsTest object is created and added to a strongly typed List.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ClsTest {

  private final int intid;

  public ClsTest(int intid) {
    this.intid = intid;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (! (o instanceof ClsTest)) {
      return false;
    }
    ClsTest that = (ClsTest)o;
    return this.intid == that.intid;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return intid;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClsTest objtest = new ClsTest(1);
    List<ClsTest> list = new ArrayList<ClsTest>();
    list.add(objtest);

    // because we implemented equals, this returns true
    boolean b = list.contains(new ClsTest(1));

    // see what happens if you comment out ClsTst.equals
    System.err.println(b);
  }

}
```